# can I run export DISPLAY with PHP?

Tags: php, linux, export

If I try to run the command export DISPLAY inside my PHP script it fails to work but if I run it via command line it does work.  Is this a known issue or is there a better way?

The script is being called via a webpage.

My PHP command:

```
$process = 'export DISPLAY=:0 && ' . $command;
exec("$process $htmlname $exportname");
```

The error I see when running from the webpage is:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: Why do you ask? You might `exec("env DISPLAY=:0 $process $htmlname $exportname");` but this probably should not work (because a web server runs outside of your display, usually remotely). I've got the feeling you don't understand X11 basics.

Comment: Also, is this PHP script running from your shell, or being launched by a web server?  Give us ALL the information, or we don't know which way to point you.

Comment: export is a shell built-in command, not an executable. unelss you're actually running a shell inside that exec() call, it'll just be "no such file/command".

Comment: Is the web server the same machine runningX?  If so, then the `DISPLAY` variable you've set definitely won't work, as it refers to localhost.  Also, read the man page for [`xhost`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=xhost&manpath=FreeBSD+Ports).

Comment: @Graham It is the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up environment before system call with e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php . This could cause a window open on the webserver desktop. You might also need to disable X11 xauth authentication with xhost +